# Angular http.post nested json

Tags: json, angular, symfony, angular5

I'm working with Angular5 and Symfony 3.4 with FOSUserBundle.

I have something like :

```
register(username: string, email: string, first: string, second: string)
{
  return this.appHttp.post('register', {username, email, first, second}).subscribe(
    data => {
       this.appHttp.logRequest(data);
    }
  );
}
```

And what i need to send to API is a formated json like :

```
{
  "email": "email@test.com",
  "username" : "userTest",
  "plainPassword" : {
    "first" : "123",
    "second": "123"
   }
}
```

Currently, my json looks like :

```
{
  "email": "email@test.com",
  "username" : "userTest",
  "first": "123",
  "second": "123",
}
```

How can i post the required json ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Change :

```
{username, email, first, second}
```

To

```
{username, email, plainPassword : {first, second} }
```